# Ensure correctness in riak?

Tags: transactions, riak

It appears you cant do transactions in riak. How does one ensure data is correct?

Lets say we want to insert a comments. In redis i'd do

```
commentId=incr commentCount
multi
SET comment_post:commentId postId //for later use when we flag comments. We'll need to know where in the db it is
RPUSH post_comment:postId binaryValue //contains commentId in it + comment body
exec
```

In sql i'd insert a new row in a comment table with the text and post id.
Both use more then one statement. How do i both insert the comment body and associate the post to the comment in riak as it has no transactions?

Another problem is if i modify a post. How do i update the post and update the tag list of post using that tag

Answer (score 6):

Riak is an eventually consistent system designed to be write available and has no concept of atomicity; there are no <strike>atomic counters or</strike> transactions.

**Edit:** We released counters using CRDTs in Riak 1.4. For details see [Counters in Riak 1.4](http://basho.com/counters-in-riak-1-4/)

The approach used by Riak is based on the Amazon Dynamo paper and uses vector clocks for conflict resolution; it's a read/modify/write cycle with any conflict resolution performed during a subsequent read. At any given time you can have multiple values for a given key that will all be returned when doing a fetch.

it *sounds* like you want to look at our [secondary indexes](http://wiki.basho.com/Secondary-Indexes.html) (if I'm understanding your scenario; the fact that you need a new `commentId` for a 'like' is somewhat confusing without knowing more). You would create a secondary index that pointed at your comment body that gets sent along with the body itself when you do a store. That solves at least one half of the problem.

How you get your `commentId` is a little trickier. You can't use a global atomic counter because we don't have them. Your design would need to either not rely on sequential IDs (perhaps generate UUIDs?) and perhaps use our [links](http://wiki.basho.com/Links.html) ?

If you're interested and would like to discuss possible design approaches, please ping us on the [riak-users mailing list](http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com) - all of our engineers read it and are always happy to answer questions.

Comment: I don't know much about riak as i took a brief look at it. When I know the basics or more i'll post there but not right now. I want to get a general idea what its suitable for as i found out redis is bad at being a db since it has to be able to fit everything in memory. I don't know a thing about `vector clocks` but you just said i can have multiple values for a key which sounds weird but i'll pretend riak is pretty efficient. So riak is designed to have all consistency logic done by the app? Thats interesting

Comment: I did a bit of reading. I'm a bit confused bc the example showed setting allow_mult being set to true. So what happens if i have something that has a write conflict and is false... So it sounds like everything has a vclock in it? It appears you making write available high. I can see the use and tradeoff there. I can imagine how to resolve and correct things for my needs but i cant imagine/think of what happens if i didnt set multis and it is false? Will one overwrite the other? Will it fail? I can see how to handle things if it fails (but i'll have to undo other writes)

Comment: but i cant see what happens if it doesnt fail and one job finished while the other job started and finished a bit after it and overwrote data.